# Taking the sum in for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

This question may sound to be similar to other questions, but when I check them they are a bit different from what I'm looking for. Here's my code below,

```
Data <- rbind(c(54, 55, 51), c(52, 51, 57))
WMatrix <- rbind(c(0, 1), c(1, 0)) 

for(i in 1:2){
   for(j in 1:2){
      for(t in 1:2){
      print(WMatrix[i,j]*Data[j,t]*Data[i,t+1])
      }
   }
}
```

The output of this codes is,

```
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 2860
[1] 2601
[1] 2754
[1] 3135
[1] 0
[1] 0
```

Now, ***I want to have the sum of this output generated immediately from the loop (without listing it). That is, the output of the loop should be 11350, which is the sum of all generated outputs in the loop***. I know this problem could be very simple, but I'm still learning basic programming. I tried this,

```
for(i in 1:2){
   for(j in 1:2){
      for(t in 1:2){
      print(sum(WMatrix[i,j]*Data[j,t]*Data[i,t+1]))
      }
   }
}
```

But, the output is still the same, can someone help me on this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why don't you express what you want done in words?  It's hard to help if we don't know what you're aiming to get.

Comment: Ahm, sorry sir, but I decided to give an example here, which for me would be easy to look on the problem. My only aim here is to get the sum of those (2860, 2601, ..., etc) immediately from the loop I made. That is, I want the sum of all the ouputs, instead of having a list of it, like the one above.

Comment: I want the generated output from my loop to be 11350, which is just the sum of 2860, 2601, ..., etc.

Comment: Yes, and how did you calculate 2860, 2601, etc.  The reason I ask is that your problem can almost certainly be vectorized--and be much faster and much clearer as a result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A little bit of matrix algebra and you're done in one step:

```
sum(WMatrix * (Data[, -3] %*% Data[, -1]))
[1] 11350
```

---

**Edit:** In R the `*` operator performs elementwise multiplication, while `%*%` gives the matrix product.

Comment: Wow, I didn't have the will to go through the indices to even try to guess what he tries to do.

Comment: @Andrie, you have your description of the operators backwards (BTW the elementwise multiplication performed by `*` is sometimes called the *Hadamard product* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_%28matrices%29 )

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm trying actually to make a simple function... But, I only knew about the for loops... I will try your answer andrie.

Comment: @BenBolker <facepalm>Thank you for pointing this out. I have edited my answer.</facepalm>

Comment: @Andrie, I can't understand why you assigned -3 and -1 on the Data columns. I'm sorry but I don't get it. I'm trying to review on matrix, but I just can't make a pattern into your answer. Can you help me explain that why? Thanks...

Comment: `Data[, -3]` means drop the third column, while `Data[, -1` means drop the first column. This is exactly what you do in your code, i.e. when you write `Data[j, t]` and `Data[j, t+1]` you multiply the first column with the second, the second with the third, etc. If you wanted to generalize, you would have to count the number of columns and drop the last column, e.g. `Data[, -ncol(Data)]`

Answer (score 3):

Here, this is totally inefficient, reads like C code etc., but prints what you want, I guess. I would not optimize the code without knowing what you actually try to achieve here, what these operations are.

**EDIT: see the much superior alternative answer. @Andrie actually guessed what you *wanted* to do.**

```
sum <- 0 
for(i in 1:2){
  for(j in 1:2){
    for(t in 1:2){
      sum <- sum + WMatrix[i,j]*Data[j,t]*Data[i,t+1]
    }
  }
}
print( sum )
```